# android build failed gradle cant resolve

Tags: android, maven, cordova, android-studio, gradle

error:

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>   Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
>        Required by:
>            project :
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools    /build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build    /gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom'.
>   jcenter.bintray.com
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
>   Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/bu    ild/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gr    adle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom'.
>   dl.google.com

while i can download *gradle-3.0.1.pom* in my browser.

my env:

```
android studio 3.2.1
cordova 8.1.2
win 10
```

I tried to force *gradle-wrapper.properties* to use http for

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

but no succuss.
I removed and reinstalled cordova,android studio and sdk build tools to latest versions and problem is still remain.

my build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    //This replaces project.properties w.r.t. build settings
    project.ext {
      defaultBuildToolsVersion="27.0.1" //String
      defaultMinSdkVersion=19 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 4.4
      defaultTargetSdkVersion=27 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default
      defaultCompileSdkVersion=27 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

changing maven url to google() is not working.
enable *embedded maven repository* in android studio is not a solution.

Comment: try changing gradle version 3.0.1 to 3.2.0

Comment: and also try commenting project.ext{...} code block

Comment: @ErangaGamagedara still same error with 3.2.0, I have not extra properties in my build.gradle ( I think cordova do not use that)

Comment: did you tried removing  project.ext{...}

Comment: and you dont need to use that google mavan url, replace it with google()

Comment: @ErangaGamagedara  removing maven and using just google() cuases: `   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.0/gradle-3.2.0.pom
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.0/gradle-3.2.0.jar`

Comment: @ErangaGamagedara And no I didnt tried to removing ext, I never saw it in build.gradle in my cordova projects.maybe it is somewhere else,is it posible?

Comment: brother, in android studio you can see gradle top rite side. you can execute gradle tasks manually in there. first execute task uninstall in root>Install>uninstallAll. after uninstalling all sync project. i think it will fix your problem. we cant say exact solution without looking your gradle files.

Comment: also try deleting local maven repositories .m2 folder etc.

Comment: @ErangaGamagedara sorry dude, still not working...even reinstalling gradle isnt working. sync process failed with `can not resolve classPath` (after downloading gradle4.1-all.zip)